# Can Mathematica Accurately Integrate the Absolute Value of Functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function, and I want to find the antiderivative of the absolute value of a function $|f(x)|$.

`Integrate[Abs[(6 + 5 Sin[3 x] + 7 Sin[4 x])^2 - 0.5], x, Assumptions -> Element[Alternatives[x], Reals]]`

However, I want to know-- is it correct on $[0, \infty)$? I tried using `NIntegrate` to check it, and it only seemed off by a few decimal points. I don't know if this signifies something fundamentally wrong with it, or just machine error?

Comment: Even `Integrate[RealAbs[(6 + 5 Sin[3 t] + 7 Sin[4 t])^2 - 1/2], {t, 0, 2}]` produces a long output in terms of roots of polynomials of degree 16 in approximately 62 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an accurate result, replace 0.5 by 1/2.
Note, Alternatives[x] makes no sense, replace it by x.
Make your tests with rational Numbers, not real ones and use Integrate not NIntegrate. Calculating with real numbers always gives slight differences.
Finally, you can make a Monte Carlo Test with random rational Numbers to test your result.
E.g.:

```
NumberOfTests = 10^2;
f[x_] = Integrate[Abs[(6 + 5 Sin[3 x] + 7 Sin[4 x])^2 - 1/2], x, 
   Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]];
And @@ ( f'[x] == Abs[(6 + 5 Sin[3 x] + 7 Sin[4 x])^2 - 1/2] /. 
     x -> # & /@ (Table[RandomInteger[10^4], NumberOfTests]/
     Table[RandomInteger[10^4], NumberOfTests]))
```

Comment: The result leaves much to be desired: look at `Plot[Integrate[Evaluate[Abs[(6 + 5 Sin[3 x] + 7 Sin[4 x])^2 - 1/2], x,     Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]], {x, -8, 8}]`.